# Getting UNIQUE constraint failed: tbl_data.id (Sqlite code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY) error in android studio room

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio, android-room

I'm getting this error while i have initialize the id as primary key and i added the unique attribute.

Data class code :

```
    @Entity(tableName = "tbl_data" , indices = {@Index(value = {"id"},
    unique = true)})
    public class Data {
    @PrimaryKey
    private Integer id ;
    private Integer year;
    private Double dowry;

public Data(Integer id,Integer year, Double dowry) {
    this.id = id;
    this.year = year;
    this.dowry = dowry;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}
public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}
public Double getDowry() {
    return dowry;
}
public void setDowry(Double dowry) {
    this.dowry = dowry;
}
```

Data Base Class code :

```
@Database(version = 1 , exportSchema = false , entities = {Data.class} )
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
private static AppDatabase appDatabase;

public static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context) {
    if (appDatabase == null)
        appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
AppDatabase.class,
                "db_app")
                .allowMainThreadQueries().fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build();
        return appDatabase;
    }

    public abstract DataDao getDataDao();
}
```

and main activity code :

```
    db = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(this);
    dataDao = db.getDataDao();

    dataDao.insertC(new Data(1,1315, 0.004 ), new Data(2,1316, 0.005), new Data(3,1317,  0.006), new Data(4,1318, 0.007));
```

and full error in logat :

> 2021-11-07 12:20:45.070 24994-24994/com.mohajer.kitset2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.mohajer.kitset2, PID: 24994
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mohajer.kitset2/com.mohajer.kitset2.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: tbl_data.id (Sqlite code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3430)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: tbl_data.id (Sqlite code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:841)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:803)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
> at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeInsert(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:51)
> at androidx.room.EntityInsertionAdapter.insertAndReturnIdsArrayBox(EntityInsertionAdapter.java:199)
> at com.mohajer.kitset2.DataDao_Impl.insertC(DataDao_Impl.java:50)
> at com.mohajer.kitset2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7458)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7448)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1286)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3614) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:86) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2199) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using @PrimaryKey implies a UNIQUE constraint so there is no need for a unique index on the id column (the index is just a waste).

Hard coding the inserts with id values when inserting (without an onConflict constraint that IGNOREs the conflict) will, after running once from a fresh install (a rerun), result in the the UNIQUE conflict as id's 1,2,3 and 4 already exist.

Coding the @Dao as `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)` will ignore the conflict without failing and not insert the duplicates.

Comment: once again tnx a lot for your help and the time you put to answer my question. i have added the @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE) and it worked. but i at first i made the id auto generate and it cues the duplicate rows again. so i remove the line and made it Hard coded again it work and the table didn't had the duplicated rows anymore and it didn't crash again.

Comment: i have another question , can i set the year as primary key ? cues when i put the annotation before the year i received errors in Logcat and im not even using the id in this app and the value of the year is unique

Comment: @danimohajer Yes you can set the year as the primary key. You can also not have the id column. You cannot have `@PrimaryKey` coded twice (if you want a composite primary key the you can use the primarykeys parameter (similar to indicies)). Note that after you make changes then you should uninstall the app (deletes the database so the database is created again) or increase the version number in the `@Database` (the .fallBackToDestructiveMigrattion will effectively delete the database and it will be created again).

Comment: just did that and it worked , tnx a lot.